# Detect the presence of a device when it's hot plugged in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hotplugging

I am running the SPI [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c) on the panda board and I want to know which function in the [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c) is responsible for detecting the device when it's hot plugged.

Can somebody with the background of embedded systems, Linux device drivers and/or spi please answer my question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the line in your code that does the magic:

```
1286 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, omap_mcspi_of_match);
```

**Process:**
 1. Driver for each device exposes its information using the API `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE`. Each device has  a unique `vendor Id` and `device Id`.
 2. At compilation time, the build process extracts this information out of the driver and builds a table.
 3. When the device is plugged in, the `kernel` checks this `device table` to see if any `driver` is
    available for the particular `Vendor/Device Id`. If yes then it loads that driver and initializes the device.

---

Read following articles for more info:

1. http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2617/
2. http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/5604/print

Comment: can you please explain the structure members of of_device_id
I searched online, but I couldn't find the explanation.

Comment: Especially explanation of the member .data

Comment: Read the 2nd link, it's explained under `Preprocessor Abuse` .

Comment: Is it called `device table`? I'm trying to query on google `linux print device table` *(e.g. to determine whether there is a driver for given product, vendor IDs)*, but see nothing relevant.

Comment: Nevermind, I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26132/how-to-assign-usb-driver-to-device) that I can look it up in the file  `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias`. I don't quite understand though what is the relation between the file and your `device table`.

Comment: the links provided are no longer valid :(

Comment: @nightwatch Here are working links http://web.archive.org/web/20141216112516/http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2617/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20161108061014/http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/5604/print -- I tried to amend the answer, but the edit queue was full already.

Comment: @brokenfoot - does the `struct pci_device_id my_pci_tbl` that I define and add to the  MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, my_pci_tbl);` ALSO HAS to be set in the (PCI in this case) `id_table` of the `struct pci_driver pchar_driver =
{
    .name       = "my pci device",
    .id_table   = my_pci_tbl,                                                                                                               .probe = my_probe_function,                                                                                                   remove = my_remove_function,}