# How to insert my driver automatically on the insertion of USB mouse in Linux System?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I know that on the insertion of any usb device in the Linux system a specific device driver got loaded. Now I want to insert my driver on the insertion of USB mouse.

I know that I can do this task using two approaches: by using depmod or using udev concept. I have read a few things about it on the Internet but I don't get the exact answer. Can anyone suggest which approach is best to use and for that in the Linux kernel tree where I need to make changes?

Comment: *"insert my driver"* -- "Insert" into what? How is this "insertion" different from *loading* a driver module?

Comment: @sawdust it isn't different.

Comment: Are you programming a new driver for your device as a kernel module? Or are you just looking for a way to load some driver module besides whatever default udev/kernel/modprobe pops into kernel when you insert your device?

Comment: I am just looking for a way to load my driver module (e.g simple Hello.ko) beside the default activity on the usb mouse insertion.

Comment: Go through the answer in the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175960/which-drivers-are-used-by-usb-mouse-in-linux-kernel/25182401#25182401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I follow the udev approach to load module automatically on the USB insertion

Below is the procedure to load your Driver automatically on the Insertion of Hot plug-gable device (I experiment with the USB mouse and below procedure is working fine for it)

1. Run Following command

   **cmd > udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/mouse)**

   In place of ?? in the above command user need to add the device ID based on its entry in   /dev (e.g.for USB flash drive: sdb1 or sda1 etc. based on the device identity)
2. Get the Value of the below parameters from the output of above command
   **KERNEL, ATTRS{idVendor}, ATTRS{idProduct}, ATTRS{serial}**
3. Go to /etc/dev/rule.d directory and Add your rule

   **cmd > sudo vim 40-usbmouse.rules 
    ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6387", ATTRS{serial}    =="4EPLXAXE", SYMLINK+="usbpd", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/InsertModule.sh"**

   Save this file.
   Above rule is defined for the USB Mouse.
   Parameter SYMLINK creates a link of your device in the /dev directory and In RUN+ you can give your script location which is going to execute on your device insertion.

   For more info on How to write a rule refer below link

   **http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/**
4. Now after you define your rule user need to restart the udev to take your rule in notice by kernel.
   **cmd > sudo stop udev**

   **cmd > sudo start udev**
5. Insert your USB and validate that your script which you define in your rule shows its effact.
   For Mouse user can use below command

   **cmd > udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/mouse)**

P.S.: cmd stands for the command shell (Terminal).The above procedure is working with any USB device.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `MODULE_SOFTDEP` macro defined in `module.h` in your driver where you can specify the name of the USB driver which gets loaded when the USB mouse is inserted. This will load your driver automatically. The `depmod` approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` macro. That will export supported device table so that your hotplug tool (whether it udev or something else) can load your module. I've described the loading process in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228315/2538771).

To see example usage, refer to [drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c). If this driver compiled as module, it is loaded every time any usb mouse is attached.