# Use of MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE in IIO driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have an IIO driver for my ambient light sensor. The driver code makes use of MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE macro with the first argument as "i2c" and once as "of". AFAIK, MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE macro is used primarily in USB drivers to enable hot-plugging.

Could anyone please explain to me what does this macro do and what do "of" and "i2c" paramters stand for ?

Comment: Dupliacte of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901282/hard-time-in-understanding-module-device-tableusb-id-table-usage ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard time in understanding MODULE\_DEVICE\_TABLE(usb, id\_table) usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901282/hard-time-in-understanding-module-device-tableusb-id-table-usage)